# Error when using wx.StaticBitmap.SetBitmap

Tags: bitmap, wxpython

I wrote a program in python which can download pictures from the web.
For every downloaded picture it is doing a preview of that picture in the GUI but every time it does so I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 14665, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 14665, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 14665, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 14665, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Funny thing: it still works. But what does this error mean? And how can I fix it?

The code which is causing this error should be this line:

```
wx.CallAfter(self.image.SetBitmap, wx.BitmapFromImage(wx.Image(imagePath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).Rescale(width, height)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your problem with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Title")

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        button = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Load image")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ChangeImage)
        box.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.image = wx.StaticBitmap(panel)
        box.Add(self.image, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        panel.SetSizer(box)
        panel.Layout()

    def ChangeImage(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.image.SetBitmap, wx.BitmapFromImage(wx.Image("modernart.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).Rescale(150, 150)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    top = Frame()
    top.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

(You will need a `modernart.png` image in the same folder.  I'll leave it up to you to create it.)

If I replaced `self.image.setBitmap` in the call to `wx.CallAfter` with `None`, then I was able to reproduce your error.

Are you calling `wx.CallAfter` somewhere other than the line you've shown above?

Comment: Actually I call it quite often since I update different TextCtrl in my GUI. There is only one wx.CallAfter replacing the image though. And I am not always using a .png. The images can have a .jpg format, too.

Comment: The error essentially means that the callable being passed to `wx.CallAfter` is `None`.  It matters not what the image is.  I'd recommend going through all your usages of `wx.CallAfter` and checking that you're not accidentally calling the callable instead of passing the callable itself (e.g. you're writing `wx.CallAfter(self.myMethod(), ...)` when you should be writing `wx.CallAfter(self.myMethod, ...)`).

Comment: Alternatively, edit `CallAfter` in `_core.py` to throw an exception if the `callable` parameter passed in is `None`.  That might help you find the problem more quickly.

Comment: I'll try that and tell you if it helps, though I don't think I call it "wrong". If that was the case it wouldn't actually work I guess?

Comment: I solved the problem. You were giving me the hint that helped me finding it. Actually it wasn't the SetBitmap which caused the problem. I forgot that at the same time I display the name of the picture. In the method where I do that I was using `WriteText(text)` instead of `WriteText, text`. Thank you!

Comment: I suspected the error wasn't in the line of code above.  However, I didn't have all of your code so I couldn't be sure.  Nonetheless, I'm glad that you managed to solve your problem.